# Regular expression matching with any string at the end

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string

I have a script file which I'm trying to load and I cannot seem to get my regular expression to work. I'm a tad rusty with my regular expressions, but I'm surprised mine didn't work.

Basically, every line (except blank lines and those beginning with a comment ("//")) should take the following format:

```
[decimal number],[hex number],[hex number],[any string of characters]
```

So for example, every non-blank or fully commented line should look like this:

```
01, 0x00100204, 0x00000000, some string goes here
```

My match pattern is as follows

```
"[0-9]+[\\s]+,0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+[\\s]+,0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+[\\s]+,"
```

I left off the tail, (where the string goes) because, from my understanding of regex, it'll match so long as it can find a substring which matches the match pattern. Am I making the correct assumption here?

----edit -----
I also want to note that I don't care how many spaces are between the end of the number and the next comma, hence the `[\\s]+`.

Comment: The format and example dont match. There are no spaces in the format, but there is a space after the `,` in the example, and your regex is searching for spaces before the `,`

Comment: It is not clear what you want. You just want to know if a line matches your regex or do you want to catch the trailing string? Please be more specific about what you want to obtain.

Comment: You will want to use `*` instead of `+` to count "don't cares" in your spaces, since `+` will match one or more, `*` is zero or more

Comment: You can check your regexes with online testers. See http://regex101.com/ or http://regexpal.com/ for instance.

Comment: Thanks for the tip Ryan, I didn't know about that one

Comment: @MariusBancila hmm, I didn't know about these testers either. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put comma before `\s+` in your regex pattern.

choose as per your need. `\s` match any white space character `[\r\n\t\f ]`. If you looking only for space then use space instead of `\s`

```
\s*   zero or more times
\s+   one or more times
\s?   zero or one times
```

Comment: He's probably escaping them.

Comment: there is no need to escape in `[]`.

Comment: If he's using a managed language in which '\' is treated specially, then yes he will

Comment: Yup, misplaced commas did it. But visual studio was yelling at me when I didn't escape them. I suppose because I didn't use `@` before the string instantiation. So yes, I am escaping them.

Comment: @audiFanatic yes as per output you misplaced commas.

Comment: I should point out that the comment in the post: `I also want to note that I don't care how many spaces are between the end of the number and the next comma, hence the [\\s]+.` that the solution specified will not quite catch this, as it will assume NO spaces, not "don't care"

Comment: `\s` is already a character class, no need to use squares. To match many white spaces just use `\s*` or `\s+`. That `[\s]` makes my eyes bleed...

Comment: @pid I just left it as it is to make it consistent as per OP regex pattern.

Comment: Well... ok, it still matches but it's not a good practice. On the other hand you reduced the noise between the question and the answer so I removed my -1 :)

Answer (score 2):

Your regex should look like this instead:

```
"[0-9]+,\\s*0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+,\\s*0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+,\\s*"
```

A better approach to match the entire string would be:

```
@"(?mi)^[0-9]+,\s*0x[0-9a-f]+,\s*0x[0-9a-f]+,.*$"
```

If you know you will always have `1` or more whitespace characters between then use `\s+` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Switching places between space and comma should help:

```
@"\d+,\s*0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+,\s*0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+,\s*"
```

The initial `@` helps with escapes and you shouldn't write `[\s]+` because `\s` is already a character class, much like `\d`.

Answer (score 1):

Use verbatim strings (introduced with `@`). Backslashes don't need to be escaped in verbatim strings.

Use the `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase` option, instead of providing lower- and uppercase variants.

```
string pattern = @"^\d+,\s*0x[0-9a-f]+,\s*0x[0-9a-f]+,.*$";
MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(input, pattern,
                                    RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

`^` and `$` match the beginning and end of lines. If your input string contains all the lines, use the `RegexOptions.Multiline` option in order to make `^` and `$` match the beginning and end of any line, and not just the beginning and end of the entire string.

Answer (score 1):

This one can help you out, each segment is available in group as well:

```
([0-9]+),[\s]+(0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+,\s+)(0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+,\s+)(.+)
```

#### [Live Demo](http://rubular.com/r/SdqTlUk2Wo)

You can use `\d` in place of `[0-9]` and alter this pattern to exclude anything you don;t want in a group.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need regex here. A simple *Split* is enough

```
string input = "01, 0x00100204, 0x00000000, some string goes here";

var parts = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }, 4, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: I need to ensure that the second and third numbers are in hex format, so that won't work entirely

Comment: @audiFanatic Then  how does your regex parse a **decimal number**? http://www.mathsisfun.com/decimals-menu.html

Comment: The first number is a always a decimal, which `[0-9]+` takes care of. The second and third are hex, so I need to add `0x[0-9a-fA-F]+` to ensure that it doesn't exclude any hex characters

Comment: @audiFanatic a decimal number is in the form of `123.456` (BTW: it can be 123,456 depending on the *Culture*)

Comment: Let me clarify. When I say decimal, I'm talking about the base of the number (binary, octal, decimal, hexadecimal, etc). To be more specific, I'm talking about integers; the first number will always be a decimal integer, not a floating point number. I'm talking `decimal` in the computer science sense of the word; not the mathematical sense.